# How to play a video at 200% zoom on Mac?

Tags: macos, preview, quicktime

Is there a way to play a video at 200% zoom on Mac with builtin programs like Preview or Quicktime?

Or do you need to install a third party video player like VLC?

Comment: Even VLC cannot zoom in more than "Fit to Screen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the simplest way to zoom in on a video beyond "fit to screen" is to use the Mac OS builtin Accessibility Zoom feature. I could not find any application that could do it (Finder Preview, Quicktime, VLC, MPV).

Go to `System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom` to see your keyboard/mouse shortcuts. For example, on my system I can use `ctrl + 2 finger trackpad scroll` to zoom in/out. Or `opt + cmd + =/-` with the keyboard. After you zoom in, you can use the mouse to pan around.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't any option to set a precise zoom value for a video playing in QuickTime, you can still zoom the video using various means:

1. **Increase Size** command under **View** menu. Invoking this zooms the video in fixed increments.

[image]

[image]

2. **Fit to Screen** command under **View** menu. Invoking this fits the video to match with screen width/height.

[image]

3. **Zoom** command under **Window** menu. This command works similar to **Fit to Screen** command.

[image]

In addition to above, a QuickTime or quick look preview window can be freely resized with the help of resizing handles to manually adjust zoom.

Comment: I think the "Increase Size" option in Quicktime is only available if the video resolution is smaller than the display resolution. So if I have a video 1920x1080, the max zoom Quicktime will allow is "Fit to Screen". "Actual Size" and "Increase Size" are grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but another useful tip is that you can view videos full size by opening them in your browser of choice.  I rarely need to view a video at more than 200% as I wouldn't get to see any more detail.  But an annoying limitation of QT and most video players is that even if you have a high res video you can't view it at a higher resolution than your screen.  If you open it in a browser though, you can reverse pinch to zoom in to full size.  To view a local video in chrome, press cmd + o on your keyboard then use the dialog to browse and select the video you want to open.